# Make text (TextView) and Icon center in SpannableString

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, spannablestring

I've created a SpannableString with an icon in the middle. And it looks like this

[image]

As you can see here, the text is not aligned with the icon's center.

I've tried adding `ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE` but it doesnt work. I've also tried gravity in Textview.

Here's my sample code:

```kotlin
fun showTextWithIcon(){
        val text = "Hey this is my text"
        val spannableString = SpannableString(text)

        val iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_icon)
        val iconSize = binding.textview.textSize.roundToInt()
        iconDrawable!!.setBounds(0, 0, iconDrawable.intrinsicHeight, iconDrawable.intrinsicWidth)
        val imageSpan = ImageSpan(iconDrawable)

        spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, text.length /2, text.length/2+1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        binding.textview.text = spannableString
}
```